# How do I keep the screen turned on while debugging in Android?

Tags: android, debugging

Settings the developer's flag "Stay awake" might result in constant battery drain of your debugging device. So, how can you easily keep the device screen on ONLY while debugging?

Comment: Enable 'Stay Awake' in Developer Options section. Stay Awake = Screen will never sleep while charging

Comment: Charging is extremely slow while screen on... which means empty battery. I have a Samsung Galaxy S6/S4. Same on both...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try
{
if( BuildConfig.DEBUG && Debug.isDebuggerConnected() )
{
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
else
{
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You what to dismiss keyguard as well. This flag is not enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**this is for vertical**

```
  //vetical position
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // Make to run your application only in portrait mode
```

**this is for screen always screen on**

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: You want to dismiss keyguard as well... see my answer

Comment: wr is ur answer

Comment: are you developer... simple think to manually keep it on to timeout in your device.. my answer useful for some other ok.